# Difference between PreparedStatement when using different driver

Tags: java, mysql

I want to know which is faster and reliable from below drivers.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement - mysql

java.sql.PreparedStatement - jdbc
```

So which one is good to use in Java?

Comment: java.sql.PreparedStatement is an interface defining the contract for driver PreparedStatement implementations

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html

Answer (score 2):

`com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` implements `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.

Rather use `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. You don't want your code to worry about vendor specific `PreparedStatement` at all. I suggest to **always** use the API, where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The java.sql.PreparedStatement you get back from the system is actually a concrete instance of the PreparedStatement implementation by your database driver. For example, if you're using the mysql driver, what you get back is actually an instance of the `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` class you're asking to compare it to.

You can see the code for the MySQL version [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java.html), where you can see it implements the java.sql.PreparedStatement interface.

```
public class PreparedStatement 
        extends com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl 
        implements java.sql.PreparedStatement {
    ...
```

From my experience, the only time I've even wanted to bother casting it to a `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement` is to be able to be able to get the String rep for the statement plus its inputs... which can be handy for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick with the `java.sql` interface types.  I see no reason to drop down to the vendor-specific implementations.  You gain little or nothing; you lose portability.

Comment: I'd prefer a vote up and accepting a helpful answer to your thanks.  Save yourself the keystrokes.  It's good for me and good for you.